# android application mute and unmute MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-activity, media-player, mute

i was struggling for this for one day and the issue is still there.

I have 2 function in my activity which is mute and unmute as below:

```
private void mute() {
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
}

public void unmute() {
      AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
      am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
    }
```

Within the activity itself this 2 function work fine. However, when it is muted in the first activity and I want to unmute it for the next activity, the activity remain mute. I am wondering why? Could anyone please give me some advice? Thanks a lot!

Updated:
This is part of the code:

```
 ImagePlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                        {
                            // Perform button logic
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v)
                            {
                                unmute();
                                onResume();
                                Speaker = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageSpeaker);    
                                Speaker.setImageBitmap(mAudioImageArray[0]);
                                closeDialog.dismiss();
                                play(DOSParseActivity.this,introAudioPath);
                                isMute = false;
                            }
                        });

                        ImageMute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                        {
                            // Perform button logic
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v)
                            {
                                Speaker = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageSpeaker);    
                                Speaker.setImageBitmap(mAudioImageArray[1]);
                                closeDialog.dismiss();
                                mute();
                                onPause();
                                isMute = true;
                            }
                        });

                        ImageStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                        {
                            // Perform button logic
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v)
                            {
                                Speaker = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageSpeaker);    
                                Speaker.setImageBitmap(mAudioImageArray[2]);
                                closeDialog.dismiss();
                                stop();
                                isMute = false;
                            }
                        });

            /////////////////////////////////////Navigation Button////////////////////////////
                        imageNext = new ImageButton(this);
                        InputStream toNextInput = mngr.open(toNextImage);
                        final Bitmap bitmaptoNext = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(toNextInput);
                        imageNext = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageNext);
                        imageNext.setImageBitmap(bitmaptoNext);
                        imageNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                        {
                            public void onClick(View v) 
                            {
                                stop();
                                Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmaptoNext, 54, 54, true);
                                imageNext.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);

                                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Characteristic.class);

                                intent.putExtra("checkMute", "mute" );
                                intent.putExtra("languageSelection", languageSelected );
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        });

private void play(Context context, String file) {

    try {
        if (IntroPlayer == null) 
        {
            this.IntroPlayer = new MediaPlayer();           
        }
        else
        {
            IntroPlayer.stop();
            IntroPlayer.reset();
        }

        AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getAssets().openFd(file);
        IntroPlayer.setDataSource(
                afd.getFileDescriptor(),
                afd.getStartOffset(),
                afd.getLength()
            );
        afd.close();
        IntroPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        IntroPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        IntroPlayer.prepareAsync();

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }


 @Override
     public void onSwipe(int direction) {
      Intent intent = new Intent();

  switch (direction) {
  case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT :
      if (IntroPlayer != null) 
        {
             stop();  
        }
      intent.setClass(this,LocalizationAppActivity.class);
         intent.putExtra("languageSelection", languageSelected );
         break;

  case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT :  
    if (IntroPlayer != null) 
    {
        stop();   
    }
      intent.setClass(this,Characteristic.class);
      intent.putExtra("languageSelection", languageSelected );

      break;

  }
   startActivity(intent);

 }

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     mp.start();
}

private void stop() {
    IntroPlayer.stop();
}

private void mute() {
    am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
}

public void unmute() {
      int maxVolume = am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, maxVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
      am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
    }

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy();
     stop();


}
```

Comment: Try setting the object "am" outside of the methods, i.e. `AudioManager am(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); private void mute(){ am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true); } private void unMute(){ am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false); }`

Comment: I have try it but it is still not working. Both function work in the first activity. But when it is muted in first activity, it cant be unmute in the next activity.

Comment: Could you be muting more than once?  The documentation suggests that you need to unmute as many times as you have muted to return the volume: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamMute(int, boolean)

Comment: I don't think you can "transcend" activities like that in Android. You  need to know if it's muted or not, and then reverse the muting. So maybe a "flip" method would be more appropriate. Whatever the state is, reverse it. You could setup a "mutestate" variable and send it as an intent data object when the user goes to the next activity. Or, a class, as @parag has written is probably best.

Comment: I have updated part of my code. Could you pls help me to check it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take `public static AudioManager am` ; in one `Global.java` and u can use and set property try it will be work for u.

```
private void mute() {
    Global.am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
}

public void unmute() {
      Global.am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
      am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i am totally new in programming. Can i get to know how to create global.class?

Comment: sorry i have update my answer. global.java is a simple java class

Comment: but it is still not work. I unmute is not working for the next activity.